# CSS animation not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have this code and it works on my PC browser, and Galaxy Note 4 phone. It animates an SVG element. But when I test on a Moto X phone (Chrome browser), it does not work. Does anyone know why? I tried to put in all the prefix tags.

```css
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
#left_leg_group {
  animation: example 1s linear infinite;
  /* and here*/
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  transform-origin: 50% -10%;
}
#right_leg_group {
  animation: example 1s linear infinite;
  /* and here*/
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  transform-origin: 50% -10%;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="main">
    <g id="left_leg_group">
      <rect id="left_1" x="81" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40" />
      <rect x="81" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5" />
      <path id="foot" fill="#A07044" d="M98,180H75c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S75,169,75,169h23V180z" />
    </g>
    <g id="torso_group">
      <path fill="#653508" d="M138,141H63V65.021c0,0-1.751-29.521,37.167-29.521S138,65.021,138,65.021V141z" />
    </g>
    <g id="right_leg_group">
      <rect id="Left_3_" x="109" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40" />
      <rect x="109" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5" />
      <path id="foot_1_" fill="#AE7A49" d="M126,180h-23c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S103,169,103,169h23V180z" />
    </g>
    <g id="right_arm_group">
      <path fill="#653508" d="M138,73.21c0,0-13,0.123-13,4.957s13,5.824,13,5.824c1,0.01,0.725,0.01,1.005,0.01
     c17.58,0,31.747-14.25,31.747-31.83c0-17.19-13.752-31.2-30.752-31.81v11.43c10,1.98,19.67,10.43,19.67,20.55
     C159.67,63.15,149,72.05,138,73.21z" />
      <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M133.33,25.75c0,5.25,4.835,5.72,4.835,5.72c0.67,0.07,1.835,0.18,1.835,0.32V20.36
     c0-0.01-0.605-0.02-0.995-0.02c-0.28,0-0.478,0-0.757,0.01C138.248,20.35,133.33,20.5,133.33,25.75z" />
    </g>
    <g id="left_arm_group">
      <path fill="#653508" d="M41.206,52.34C41.206,42.22,51,33.77,61,31.79V20.36c-17,0.61-30.876,14.62-30.876,31.81
     C30.124,69.75,44.229,84,61.809,84c0.281,0-0.025,0,0.975-0.01c0,0,12.984-0.99,12.984-5.824c0-4.833-12.946-4.956-12.946-4.956
     C51.821,72.05,41.206,63.15,41.206,52.34z" />
      <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M67.422,25.75c0,5.25-4.711,5.72-4.711,5.72C62.041,31.54,61,31.65,61,31.79V20.36
     c0-0.01,0.481-0.02,0.871-0.02c0.28,0,0.416,0,0.695,0.01C62.566,20.35,67.422,20.5,67.422,25.75z" />
    </g>
    <g id="head_group">
      <circle id="face" fill="#AE7A49" cx="95.207" cy="70.543" r="28.042" />
      <path id="Right_Eye" fill="#200200" d="M82.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.07-2.38-2.38-2.38s-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
    c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S82.25,62.38,82.25,65z" />
      <path id="left_eye_1" fill="#200200" d="M106.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.069-2.38-2.38-2.38c-1.31,0-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
    c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S106.25,62.38,106.25,65z" />
      <circle id="mouth" fill="#200200" cx="89.104" cy="70.938" r="5.271" />
      <polygon id="forehead" fill="#915B36" points="104,51 81,51 81.688,49 103.312,49  " />
      <polygon id="forehead_1" fill="#915B36" points="110,56 76,56 76.75,54 109.125,54  " />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try adding @-webkit-keyframes ?

Comment: You need to add `-webkit-animation` and `@-webkit-keyframes`. Also, why are you using `animation-timing-function` when you set the timing in `animation` to `linear`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@keyframe` also needs prefixing, as does `animation`. Also, you are setting `animation-timing-function` to `ease-in-out` after explicitly setting it in `animation` (`animation: example 1s linear infinite;`).

Try this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
#left_leg_group {
  -webkit-animation: example 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: example 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  /* and here*/
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  transform-origin: 50% -10%;
}
#right_leg_group {
  -webkit-animation: example 1s ease-in-out 0.1s infinite;
  animation: example 1s ease-in-out 0.1s infinite;
  /* and here*/
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% -10%;
  transform-origin: 50% -10%;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="main">
    <g id="left_leg_group">
      <rect id="left_1" x="81" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40" />
      <rect x="81" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5" />
      <path id="foot" fill="#A07044" d="M98,180H75c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S75,169,75,169h23V180z" />
    </g>
    <g id="torso_group">
      <path fill="#653508" d="M138,141H63V65.021c0,0-1.751-29.521,37.167-29.521S138,65.021,138,65.021V141z" />
    </g>
    <g id="right_leg_group">
      <rect id="Left_3_" x="109" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40" />
      <rect x="109" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5" />
      <path id="foot_1_" fill="#AE7A49" d="M126,180h-23c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S103,169,103,169h23V180z" />
    </g>
    <g id="right_arm_group">
      <path fill="#653508" d="M138,73.21c0,0-13,0.123-13,4.957s13,5.824,13,5.824c1,0.01,0.725,0.01,1.005,0.01
     c17.58,0,31.747-14.25,31.747-31.83c0-17.19-13.752-31.2-30.752-31.81v11.43c10,1.98,19.67,10.43,19.67,20.55
     C159.67,63.15,149,72.05,138,73.21z" />
      <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M133.33,25.75c0,5.25,4.835,5.72,4.835,5.72c0.67,0.07,1.835,0.18,1.835,0.32V20.36
     c0-0.01-0.605-0.02-0.995-0.02c-0.28,0-0.478,0-0.757,0.01C138.248,20.35,133.33,20.5,133.33,25.75z" />
    </g>
    <g id="left_arm_group">
      <path fill="#653508" d="M41.206,52.34C41.206,42.22,51,33.77,61,31.79V20.36c-17,0.61-30.876,14.62-30.876,31.81
     C30.124,69.75,44.229,84,61.809,84c0.281,0-0.025,0,0.975-0.01c0,0,12.984-0.99,12.984-5.824c0-4.833-12.946-4.956-12.946-4.956
     C51.821,72.05,41.206,63.15,41.206,52.34z" />
      <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M67.422,25.75c0,5.25-4.711,5.72-4.711,5.72C62.041,31.54,61,31.65,61,31.79V20.36
     c0-0.01,0.481-0.02,0.871-0.02c0.28,0,0.416,0,0.695,0.01C62.566,20.35,67.422,20.5,67.422,25.75z" />
    </g>
    <g id="head_group">
      <circle id="face" fill="#AE7A49" cx="95.207" cy="70.543" r="28.042" />
      <path id="Right_Eye" fill="#200200" d="M82.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.07-2.38-2.38-2.38s-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
    c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S82.25,62.38,82.25,65z" />
      <path id="left_eye_1" fill="#200200" d="M106.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.069-2.38-2.38-2.38c-1.31,0-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
    c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S106.25,62.38,106.25,65z" />
      <circle id="mouth" fill="#200200" cx="89.104" cy="70.938" r="5.271" />
      <polygon id="forehead" fill="#915B36" points="104,51 81,51 81.688,49 103.312,49  " />
      <polygon id="forehead_1" fill="#915B36" points="110,56 76,56 76.75,54 109.125,54  " />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```